# Optimizing convex function over non-convex sets

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In convex optimization, we usually try to solve a problem of minimizing/maximizing a convex function over a convex set/domain. Intuitively, I think it makes sense but I'm not be able to point out the exact reason why we want the set to be convex. Most of the analysis that I've seen so far usually use the convexity of the objective function rather than the set.

1. Why is the convexity of the domain important?
2. What happens if we optimize a convex function over non-convex set?

Any insights is appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a vague and general question. are you interested in existence results for maxima/minima? Necessary conditions? Computational treatment? Please modify you post accordingly. Also explain where this problem is coming from and what your thoughts are so far.

Comment: Linear programming over nonconvex sets includes integer programming, which is a very hard class of problems.

Comment: Maximizing a convex function is **not** a convex problem.

Comment: Imagine a function whose domain is $[-1,1]\cup \{2\}$. On $[-1,1]$ we define the function to be just $f(x) = x^2$ but for $x=1$ we take $f(2) = -10$. Now imagine trying to optimize such a function.